# Could Our Sun Have A Twin Sun?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, astronomy

Would it be possible for our sun to have a twin star that could not be observed but is equal in size & density & moving at equal speeds, & are at aphelion in juxtaposed 4-point ellipses or would one star have to be dominant over the other even to exist & yet not be seen?

How could my fictional world orbit twin suns and only know about one of them?

Comment: I think when I was reading some question about an anti-earth someone mentioned the [Helios satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_(spacecraft)). This would have discovered the second sun.

Comment: I feel like this question may be off-topic; it's a What-If question, not worldbuilding.

Comment: A second star would have to be a brown dwarf so dim and so far out that we can't see it.  I think that's unlikely.  Also, vampire sun?  Is this a new click-bait term for the normal system formation process that all stars go through?

Comment: You should ask this on Astronomy.SE.

Comment: This question has been edited and put in the reopen queue.  However, it was closed because it's not asking a question about a fictional world.  Yeah.  Sometimes we're sticklers for the rules.  To reopen the question must be worded from the POV of a fictional world (e.g., "Could my fictional world orbit twin suns and only know about one of them?") with, probably, the [tag:reality-check] tag.

Comment: @JBH Personally I kind of felt that was implied in the question. I edited that in just to make it more clear. OP can roll it back or change it if they feel that it's wrong.

Comment: If I may ask, what is your ultimate goal for having this second unknown sun? It might not matter, but it could potentially help with reopening or answering the question.

Comment: The gravitational attraction between two bodies in Newtonian physics varies with the total mass of both bodies and the distance between them.  The orbital speed of one body with respect to another depends om the strength of their gravitational attraction and their distance.   The amount of time that it takes one body to orbit another depends on its orbital speed and the circumference of its orbit.  Theoretically if the mass of the other sun is stated one could calculate the size of orbit it would need to orbit the sun in exactly one Earth year, and assume it was always on the far side.

Comment: But because the other star would be many times as massive as Earth, the other star would take only a fraction of a year to orbit the Sun at Earth's distance.  The other star would have to be many times as far from the Sun as Earth is to orbit with the same orbital period as Earth.  Thus in your hypothetical solar system Earth and the two suns might be lined up and the other star always hidden behind the Sun. The gravitational interactions between the two stars and the planets would probably perturb the orbits enough for the farther star to become visible after a relatively short period.

Answer (score 5):

Unlikely I think. We'd have observed gravitational effects on other celestial bodies at the very least.

Comment: While many very detailed answers may be posted, this one is the basic truth.  Humanity would have been predicting the existence of the gravitationally-powerful body since the 1500s.  So, nope, no twin sun.

Answer (score 2):

The other sun is supposed to always hide on the other side of the first Sun from Earth?

No. Because Earth's orbit is not a perfect circle, the other sun would be peeking out from behind the first Sun from time to time.

P.S. Not to mention that having a real star (not just an anti-Earth) would have affected Earth's orbit dramatically.